# Form $ref is undefined inside of method?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a very simple Vuetify form with `ref="form"`. When I press submit, I want to validate and programmatically submit the form, however for some reason `this.$refs.form` returns undefined.

[image: undefined refs]

I'm almost hoping it's something dumb like a typo because this is so seemingly simple!

```html
<template>
  <v-form
    v-if="!submitted"
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
    name="contactForm"
    data-netlify="true"
    data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
    method="POST"
    @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input
      type="hidden"
      name="form-name"
      value="contactForm">

    ...input fields

    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col
        sm="12"
        class="text-center">
        <v-btn
          :disabled="!valid || sendingForm"
          color="accent"
          depressed
          :ripple="false"
          x-large
          type="submit">
          {{ sendingForm ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit' }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <p class="d-none">
      <label for="bot-field">Don't fill this out: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="bot-field">
    </p>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      async submit() {
        this.sendingForm = true;
        console.log('refs: ', this.$refs); <-- returns undefined for this.$refs.form
        if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
          console.log('refs: ', this.$refs); <-- also returns undefined for this.$refs.form
          this.$refs.form.submit();
          this.submitted = true;
        }
        this.sendingForm = false;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I have tried removing the `v-if` on the form, removing the `type="submit`/adding `@click="submit` on the button, removing `@submit.prevent="submit` from the form... nothing seems to be working! Has anybody run into something like this? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like an issue with the log. If you notice, it states form: VueComponent, and then log undefined.
Have you tried to fire the console.log after a this.$nextTick(), just to make sure it's something related to the dom being mounted?

Comment: Can you check if it is undefined if you logging ref  in mounted hook without async

Comment: @Cristiano I've wrapped everything inside of the `submit()` function with a nextTick, and same issue.

Comment: @DimaVak I can't seem to load a console log in the `mounted()` hook for some reason... strange.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot load a console.log? Have you tried an even simpler example, just cutting out all the inputs and just keeping the form?

Comment: ```mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          console.log('mounted ref: ', this.$refs);
        })
      }```
Doesn't show a console log.

Comment: Is this the complete code of your component? if yes, you should `export default` it, otherwise it will not be imported into the root instance, and this may be the cause of VueComponent undefined in the console.log

Comment: Sorry, I do have an `export default {}`, I was just copying things over and missed that since it's a somewhat large component.

Comment: Disregard the note about `mounted()` not displaying refs. I restarted my server and it's showing the `$refs.form` correctly now for whatever reason, however the refs inside of the `submit()` function are still erring out as stated in original post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me

```
<v-form
  ref="form"
  v-model="valid"
  name="contactform1"
  action="/contact"
  method="post"
  data-netlify="true"
  netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contactform1" />
  <v-row class="spacing6">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="pa-6">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="name"
        :rules="nameRules"
        :label="$t('common.form_name')"
        class="input"
        name="name"
        required
      />
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="pa-6">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        :label="$t('common.form_email')"
        class="input"
        name="email"
        required
      />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <div class="btn-area">
    <div class="form-control-label">
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="checkbox"
        color="primary"
        :rules="[v => !!v || 'You must agree to continue!']"
        :label="$t('common.form_terms')"
        required
      />
      <a href="#">{{ $t('common.form_privacy') }}</a>
    </div>
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      outlined
      @click="validate"
      large
      type="submit"
      value="Send message"
    >
      {{ $t('common.form_send') }}
      <v-icon class="right-icon">mdi-send</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</v-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going a slightly different route to solve this. I relied on the [Vuetify form docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#validation-with-submit-clear) as well as a [Netlify article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/07/how-to-integrate-netlify-forms-in-a-vue-app/?_ga=2.97691804.226960748.1590592416-2003072385.1590592416) about integrating forms with Vue.

```
  <template>
    <v-form
      v-if="!submitted"
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
      name="contactForm"
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
      method="POST"
      @submit.prevent="submit">
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name="form-name"
        value="contactForm">
      <v-row>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="6">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="form.firstName"
            color="primary"
            label="First Name *"
            outlined
            :rules="nameRules"
            required />
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="6">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="form.lastName"
            color="primary"
            label="Last Name *"
            outlined
            :rules="nameRules"
            required />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="form.email"
            color="primary"
            label="Email *"
            type="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            outlined
            required />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-textarea
            v-model="form.message"
            color="primary"
            label="Message *"
            outlined
            :rules="nameRules"
            required />
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          sm="12"
          class="text-center">
          <v-btn
            :disabled="!valid || sendingForm"
            color="accent"
            depressed
            :ripple="false"
            x-large
            type="submit">
            {{ sendingForm ? 'Loading...' : 'Submit' }}
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <p class="d-none">
        <label for="bot-field">Don't fill this out: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="bot-field">
      </p>
    </v-form>
  </template>

  <script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
      data: () => ({
        ...other stuff,
        emailRules: [
           v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
           v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
        ],
        form: {
          email: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          message: '',
        },
        nameRules: [
          v => !!v || 'Name is required.',
        ],
      }),

      methods: {
        encode (data) {
          return Object.keys(data)
           .map(
             key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`
           )
          .join("&");
        },
        submit () {
          this.sendingForm = true;

          const axiosConfig = {
            header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
          };

          axios
            .post(
              '/',
              this.encode({
                'form-name': 'contactForm',
                ...this.form
              }),
              axiosConfig
            )
            .then(() => this.submitted = true)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => this.sendingForm = false);
          }
       }
  </script>
```

Because validation is handled with `required` and `:rules`, I don't need to manually validate it in the submit function. And because it's tied to Netlify Forms, I have to run an axios POST with encoded form fields.

FWIW, I realized that when console logging `this.$refs`, then form appears to be undefined. However, if I console log `this.$refs.form`, then it gives me the ref as expected.